# 5 Minutes Spark Batch Job vs Streaming Job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to figure out what should be a better approach.

I have a Spark Batch Job which is scheduled to run every 5 mints and it takes 2-3 mints to execute.

Since [Spark 2.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala) have added support for dynamic allocation `spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled`, Is it a good idea to make its a streaming job which pulls data from source every 5 mints?

What are things I should keep in mind while choosing between streaming/batch job?

Answer (score 3):

Deciding between streaming vs. batch, one needs to look into various factors. I am listing some below and based on your use case, you can decide which is more suitable.

1) **Input Data Characteristics** - Continuous input vs batch input

If input data is arriving in batch, use batch processing.

Else if input data is arriving continuously, stream processing may be more useful. Consider other factors to reach to a conclusion.

2) **Output Latency**

If required latency of output is very less, consider stream processing.

Else if latency of output does not matter, choose batch processing.

3) **Batch size (time)**

A general rule of thumb is use batch processing if the batch size > 1 min otherwise stream processing is required. This is because trigerring/spawning of batch process adds latency to overall processing time.

4) **Resource Usage**

What's the usage pattern of resources in your cluster ?

Are there more batch jobs which execute when other batch jobs are done ? Having more than one batch jobs running one after other and are using cluster respurces optimally. Then having batch jobs is better option.

Batch job runs at it's schedule time and resources in cluster are idle after that. Consider running streaming job if data is arriving continuously, less resources may be required for processing and output will become available with less latency.

**There are other things to consider** - Replay, Manageability (Streaming is more complex), Existing skill of team etc.

**Regarding spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled**, I would avoid using it because if the rate of input varies a lot, executors will be killed and created very frequently which would add to latency.

Answer (score 2):

Spark Streaming is an outdated technology. Its successor is Structured Streaming.

If you do processing every 5 mins so you do batch processing. You can use the Structured Streaming framework and trigger it every 5 mins to imitate batch processing, but I usually wouldn't do that.

Structured Streaming has a lot more limitations than normal Spark. For example you can only write to Kafka or to a file, or else you need to implement the sink by yourself using Foreach sink. Also if you use a File sink then you cannot update it, but only append to it. Also there are operations that are not supported in Structured Streaming and there are actions that you cannot perform unless you do an aggrigation before.

I might use Structured Straming for batch processing if I read from or write to Kafka because they work well together and everything is pre-implemented. Another advantage of using Structured Streaming is that you automatically continue reading from the place you stopped.

For more information refer to [Structured Streaming Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).

Comment: Most of this is true but outdated